# Static network interface

Tags: network-programming, buildroot

When editing a file:
`/etc/network/interface`

Something like this:

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

and when I enter the command `make`, my interface bacome default.
How can I set a static address interface eth0 in Buildroot?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `make` overwrites your changes with the default. You need to enable **Root Filesystem Overlay**:

System Configuration -> Root Filesystem Overlay

*Root Filesystem Overlay* points to a folder in your host (`/home/user/overlay`, for instance). That folder can contain any files which will be copied to the target image before is built. Put your interface file in `overlay/etc/network/interface` and it will be copied to your target image.